# How to group by according to the values of a list present in a column in dataframe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe of movies from pandas like this

```
id, name,     genre, release_year 
1    A    [a,b,c]     2017
2    B    [b,c]       2017
3    C    [a,c]       2010
4    D    [d,c]       2010
....
```

I want to group by the movies according to the values present in the genre lists.
My expected output is:

```
year, genre, number_of_movies
2017  a       1
2017  b       2
2017  c       2
2010  a       1
2010  c       2 
...
```

Can somebody please help me to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `collections.Counter` method, which has O(n) complexity, and removes the need for `df.groupby` / `df.apply`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import product, chain
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
                   'genre': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'c'], ['a', 'c'], ['d', 'c']],
                   'year': [2017, 2017, 2010, 2010]})

c = Counter(chain.from_iterable([list(product([x['year']], x['genre'])) \
                                 for idx, x in df.iterrows()]))

# Counter({(2010, 'a'): 1,
#          (2010, 'c'): 2,
#          (2010, 'd'): 1,
#          (2017, 'a'): 1,
#          (2017, 'b'): 2,
#          (2017, 'c'): 2})

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index')

#            0
# (2017, a)  1
# (2017, b)  2
# (2017, c)  2
# (2010, a)  1
# (2010, c)  2
# (2010, d)  1
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried the solution. However my genres are : ['Adventures','comedy'..]
In that case after the 1st step I am getting output as follows:
(2016, '['): 33,
         (2016, "'"): 206,
         (2016, 'A'): 40,
         (2016, 'd'): 28,
         (2016, 'v'): 20,
         (2016, 'e'): 83,
         (2016, 'n'): 70,
         (2016, 't'): 61,
         (2016, 'u'): 21,
         (2016, 'r'): 59,
         (2016, ','): 70,
         (2016, ' '): 78,
            ....
However the expected output is 
(2016, 'Adventure'), 40
  ...

Comment: @Sitabja, I'm confused. With your input I've arrived at your desired output (except using (year, genre) as index).. so seems like either the logic is being misapplied or your data is different.

Comment: it is working, actually there was some problem with my input, which I am able to sort out. many thanks for the quick response

Answer (score 1):

You can create new `DataFrame` by contructor, reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and for count use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(df['genre'].values.tolist(), index=df['release_year'].values)
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='genre')
         .groupby(['release_year','genre'])
         .size()
         .reset_index(name='number_of_movies'))

print (df1)
   release_year genre  number_of_movies
0          2010     a                 1
1          2010     c                 2
2          2010     d                 1
3          2017     a                 1
4          2017     b                 2
5          2017     c                 2
```

Answer (score 1):

For performance, use `itertools.chain` to flatten the `genre` column:

```
from itertools import chain

df = pd.DataFrame({
      'genre' : list(
           chain.from_iterable(df.genre.tolist())
       ), 
      'release_year' : df.release_year.repeat(df.genre.str.len())
})

df
  genre  release_year
0     a          2017
0     b          2017
0     c          2017
1     b          2017
1     c          2017
2     a          2010
2     c          2010
3     d          2010
3     c          2010
```

Now, group on `genre` and `release_year` and find the `size` of each group:

```
df.groupby(
     ['genre', 'release_year'], sort=False
 ).size()\
  .reset_index(name='number_of_movies')

  genre  release_year  number_of_movies
0     a          2017                 1
1     b          2017                 2
2     c          2017                 2
3     a          2010                 1
4     c          2010                 2
5     d          2010                 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another cool method is to use `Counter` i.e

```
from collections import Counter

ndf = df.groupby('release_year')['genre'].apply(lambda x : Counter(np.concatenate(x.values))).reset_index()

ndf = ndf.set_axis('release_year,genre,number_of_movies'.split(','),inplace=False,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   release_year genre  number_of_movies
0          2010     a               1.0
1          2010     c               2.0
2          2010     d               1.0
3          2017     a               1.0
4          2017     b               2.0
5          2017     c               2.0
```